# How do I make Instagram stories open inside a web browser window and not in my windows full screen using selenium in c# with mobile user agent string?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, instagram-story

I am automating Instagram for some various options and using mobile user agent string in C#. It works all good just as a mobile phone but when I open stories, they get opened in full screen mode covering my whole computer's screen. I want to open these stories inside a browser window.
This is the string I am using,
`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30` 
I have set my browser's window size,

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(375, 667);
```

Is there any way that stories don't open covering my full desktop's screen? Because I want to open multiple accounts (10) and open their stories simultaneously.

This is how it would look,
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u42tS.jpg)

Any way possible in c# or even in python?

Comment: This sounds like a limitation of Instagram, and something that can't be overridden with Selenium -- you can set the window size, but when you open an Instagram story, I don't think you can control the window size that Instagram itself is programmed to render.

Comment: @Christine That's really depressing for me :(
But thanks for your response.